# Set My Account custom items endpoints titles in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, endpoint

I customise my woocommerce account pages by adding new endpoints successfully.
The title oh this new endpoints is "My account" default title. I would like to customize the title as well.
I tried with the hook "woocommerce_endpoint_{endpoints}_title", which works perfectly on defaults endpoints, but it doesn't seem to work on custom endpoint :

My custom endpoint (not working):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_favoris_title', 'change_my_account_favoris_title', 10, 2 );
function change_my_account_favoris_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    $title = __( "Tests", "woocommerce" );
    return $title;
}
```

[Custom endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bF7o.png)

Default endpooint example working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_edit-account_title', 'change_my_account_edit_title', 10, 2 );
function change_my_account_edit_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    $title = __( "Tests", "woocommerce" );
    return $title;
}
```

[Default endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyOch.png)

Can't find anything on this for now,
Thanks for your time

---

EDIT:

My complete hooks of my woocommerce account section:

1/ Creation of endpoints :

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_log_history_link', 40);
function custom_log_history_link($menu_links){
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 5, true )
        + array( 'favoris' => 'Mes favoris' )
        + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true )
        + array( 'delete-account' => 'Supprimer mon compte' )
        + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true );
    return $menu_links;
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_add_endpoint' );
function custom_add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'favoris', EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'delete-account', EP_PAGES);
}
```

2/ Content of new endpoints:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_favoris_endpoint', 'custom_my_account_endpoint_content_favoris' );
function custom_my_account_endpoint_content_favoris() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id=$user->ID;
    $favoris=get_field('liste_des_favoris','user_'.$user_id);
    $favoris_id=array();
    echo "<h3>Vos produits favoris :</h3>";
    if ($favoris!=''){
        foreach ($favoris as $favori) {
            $favoris_id[] = $favori['produit_favori'];
        }
        echo '<ul class="list-produits">';
        foreach($favoris as $favori){
            $product=wc_get_product($favori['produit_favori']);
            $product = $product->get_data();
            $sidebar = true;
            ItemProduit($product,$sidebar,$favoris_id,$user_id);
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo "<p>Vous n'avez pas de favoris pour le moment1.</p>";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_delete-account_endpoint', 'custom_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function custom_my_account_endpoint_content() {
    echo "<p>Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer défintivement votre compte ?<br/>Attention ! Toute suppression de compte est définitive, vous perdrez tout l'historique de vos achats.<br/>En supprimant votre compte, toutes vos données personnelles seront définitivement effacées de notre base de données.</p>";
    echo '<p class="status"></p>';
    wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-delete-nonce', 'delete-security' );
    echo '<div class="btns-delete">';
    echo '<div class="btn btn-red" id="submit-delete">Supprimer</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

3/ Custom menu order :

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_sort_menu' );
function custom_sort_menu( $menu_links ){
    $menu_links = array(
        'dashboard' => 'Tableau de bord',
        'orders' => 'Mes commandes',
        'favoris' => 'Mes favoris',
        'edit-address' => 'Mes adresses',
        'edit-account' => 'Détails du compte',
        'customer-logout' => 'Déconnexion',
        'delete-account' => 'Supprimer mon compte',
    );
    return $menu_links;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didin't see your comment before.
I just edited my initial question with everything concerning the customisation of my woocommerce account section.

Comment: I have solved this problem… see my answer below.

Comment: Yes this is perfectly what I was missing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow the composite filter hook `woocommerce_endpoint_{$endpoint}_title` to work with custom My Account endpoints, there is something missing from your code. You need to declare those endpoints as query vars in `woocommerce_get_query_vars` filter hook as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'myaccount_custom_endpoints_query_vars' );
function myaccount_custom_endpoints_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['favoris'] = 'favoris';
    $query_vars['delete-account'] = 'delete-account';

    return $query_vars;
}
```

Then to change that custom endpoints titles you can use effectively:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_favoris_title', 'change_my_account_favoris_title' );
function change_my_account_favoris_title( $title ) {
    return __( "Favoris", "woocommerce" );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_delete-account_title', 'change_my_account_delete_account_title' );
function change_my_account_delete_account_title( $title ) {
    return __( "Supprimer mon compte", "woocommerce" );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Remember to refresh rewrite rules by saving changes on Wordpress settings "Permalinks" section.

---

**Other notes:**

In your actual code, you are using 2 times the hook `woocommerce_account_menu_items` in 2 functions… You need just one of them

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect.
Thanks also for your precision to make my code cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

One way of changing the title of the custom WooCommerce endpoints is to use `the_title` filter with the `in_the_loop` conditional

Here is an example that you'll need to modify per your own requirements.

```
function wpb_woo_endpoint_title( $title, $id ) {

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) && in_the_loop() ) { // add your endpoint urls
        $title = "Download MP3s"; // change your entry-title
    }

    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = "My Orders";
    }

    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = "Change My Details";
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_woo_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your return.
But the problem is the same with this method.
The function works fine on default endpoints (type 'edit-accout') but it's not working on my custom endpoints ('favoris').

Comment: You should probably include how you created the custom endpoint, that way you may receive a working solution. @C_Com2see

Comment: Sure, I edited my initial question with everything concerning the customisation of woocommerce account section.