# Change WooCommerce Order pay page title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title, endpoint

Attempting to change the title of the "pay for order" page / "customer payment page"

`https://url.com/checkout/order-pay/753/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_xxxxxx`

Below is not currently working, it is modified from changing the title on the thank you page.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'woo_title_pay_order', 10, 2 );

function woo_title_pay_order( $title, $id ) {
if ( function_exists( 'is_pay_for_order_page' ) && 
     is_pay_for_order_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
    $title = "Checkout";
}
return $title;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated

You can use the following to change "Pay for order" page title:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_pay_for_order_title' );
function change_pay_for_order_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
        return __('Checkout', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Or also the following code based on 'order-pay' endpoint *(but changes the breadcrumb)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_order-pay_title', 'change_checkout_order_pay_title' );
function change_checkout_order_pay_title( $title ) {
    return __( "Checkout", "woocommerce" );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Set My Account custom items endpoints titles in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389629/set-my-account-custom-items-endpoints-titles-in-woocommerce/64393310#64393310)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this does appear to change the title of the breadcrumb for the pay for order page so it is functioning but the heading of the page is reverting to the name given to the checkout page, in this case its "mockup requested". So essentially, I'm trying to change the name of the checkout page but only while viewing pay for order.

Comment: Thank you for following up, even just a simple if statement that would only run on the pay order page would be useful

Comment: That did the trick and didn't alter the title other checkout pages. Thank you for sorting that out. Cheers!

Comment: Tested the revised snipped but the 1st revision was the one that worked in my use case. `&& 'Pay for order' === $title` did not have the desired effect. Thank you nonetheless